# Clicks going through viewpager containing fragments with listview in API 16

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Im having an incredibly annoying issue on android i think it might even be a bug. I have an activity with a viewpager, containing two fragments. Both fragments layouts are listviews. It works normally on everything ive tested on except any API 16 emultor on android studio. What happens is a click on the top level fragements list view item penetrates the viewpager and goes to the second tabs listview and its onclicklistener. Dont understand it. Surely the listview on top should catch everything and if not secondly the viewpager. Definitely not the under fragments listview.

I've noticed, if the second fragments listview is empty, the first fragments list view scrolls and works fine. As soon as there are items in the second fragments listview touches start to go through. This is only in lower apis and not in android 6.0 or 7.0

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

To the root of your fragment layout set

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: I tried this and it didnt work. ! The problem still persists